# How to loop through a few variable IDs?

Tags: jquery, function, checkbox, html-table

Please refer my Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/q524G/2/). I have a table with dynamic rows, each containing a checkbox with variable ID `id="monitor_'+rowID+'"`where rowID is a global variable declared without keyword `var` inside function `addText()`. I tried to use `.each(function(){});` to loop through the rows but it doesn't seem to work.

My intention is to see if the checkbox in each row is checked. If it is, a function `monitoring` will be called. 
Here is the function:

```
function monitoring() {
$('#test').append("checked");
fbType = $('td.nth(2)', $(this)).text();
fbNum = $('td.nth(3)', $(this)).text();
$('#test').append(fbType + fbNum);

$.post('/request', {
    inputText: fbNum,
    key_pressed: fbType.toString()
}).done(function (reply) {
    if (reply == "on") {
        $('#test').append("on ");
    } else {
        $('#test').append("off ");
    }
});
```

}

You can add the rows but selecting an option and add a number, then press button "Add". The first `.append("checked")` is to make sure I'm calling the function but the weird thing is, it only display once even if i have a few checkboxes and I checked them all.

Another question, I can't display the following:

```
fbType = $('td.nth(2)', $(this)).html();
fbNum = $('td.nth(3)', $(this)).html();
```

Why is it so? It is crucial because as you can see, I will be posting those data to a python function...

Please tell me what's wrong with my codes and how I should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could alter the elements in your for each loop.
And I've changed the nth-selector in your attempt to get the values.
In your example you tried a jQuery function as a CSS selector.

```
$('#monitor').click(function () {
  $('#status_table tr [id^="monitor_"]:checked').each(function () {
    monitoring($(this).parents('tr'));
  });
});

function monitoring($row) {
  $('#test').append("checked");
  fbType = $row.find('td:nth-child(2)').html();
  fbNum = $row.find('td:nth-child(3)').html();
  $('#test').append(fbType + fbNum);
}
```

Comment: ahh, so will it iterate through all the rows? i'm not really sure how .each() will iterate, although i have read the jquery API about it for many times.

Comment: This will only loop over elements which have an ID that starts with `monitor_` and it will find all checkboxes in your case, because they all apply to this selector

Comment: oh, thank you! but how can i make sure it does loop through all the checked checkboxes and calling the function? it's not able to display anything and im helpless to troubleshoot. :(

Comment: I forked your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yFtcb/ and made it a litter cleaner and included the answer to this question.

Comment: :D Thank you very much!! it's my first time seeing selector being called this way, e.g div[id$="Text"] and [id^="monitor_"], they really saved a lot of spaces. thank you for sharing it :)

Answer (score 1):

You have an algorithm problem here :

```
$('#monitor').click(function () {
   $('#status_table tr').each(function () {
       $check = $('#status_table tr #monitor_' + rowID)
       if ($check.is(':checked')) {
           monitoring();
       }
  });
});
```

You are using rowID whereas as you said it's a global var, which is then when you use .each() at the last rowID you have (if there is 3 rows, rowID = 3).

Can you try to explain what you want to do with those lines :

```
fbType = $('td.nth(2)', $(this)).html();
fbNum = $('td.nth(3)', $(this)).html();
```

Comment: so my rowID will never be `rowID = type + textInput;`? for fbType and fbNum, i'm trying to get the value of those 2 columns in whichever row that has a checked checkbox. you can play around with the Fiddle above. :)

Comment: here is a worling fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pbuyR/
What I changed: - the index is now declared at the beggining and then just incremented (more performant and you don't have to add that empty <tr>). Edit : Just watched Thomas forked, even if you go with my code, you should definetely go ahead and clean your code the way he did.
- the `check` in `$('#monitor').click()` has changed
- I changed the fbType and fbNum so they are now filled correctly
If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: oh uhh, i think you pasted the wrong fiddle. (i don't see the changes you mention) :(

Comment: Hum, it hasn't saved the changes -_- but the code I wrote in the answers = the modifications I made (just missing the index var part). As far as I could see, Thomas'code was better than mine. In this fiddle(forked from Thomas'code) I have written the index var [http://jsfiddle.net/7vaHC/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/7vaHC/1/). I think it's better to do it so for two reasons : - avoiding the empty tr in your table. - the calculus didn't need 'complex' operations anymore (searching through the DOM takes resources/time).

Comment: :D ahh i see. Thank you so much for taking the time to explain to me! +1 again for your comment ;)